# Calculate difference between remote and local sets in sql

Tags: sql, sqlite, synchronization, diff

I often find my self calculating difference between remote local data (result = items only in remotes are inserts, items only in locals are deletes, rest is updates).

Its very simple algo in higher level language:

```
query remotes
query locals

for local in locals
   if local is found in remotes
       to_update += remote
       remotes -= local
   else
       to_delete += local

to_insert = remotes

for _ in to_insert
  sql insert

for _ in to_update
  sql update

for _ in to_delete
  sql delete
```

Is there a way to do this only inside sqlite database without any java/kotlin?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at sqlite [ATTACH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)?

Comment: what would that give me? my remote items are from json from api

Comment: Ahh. Sorry I saw `query` and assumed SQL. My bad. If you want to do it "inside" sqlite database, then everything has to _be_ "inside" sqlite database, no?

Comment: now that you mentioned it youre right, id need to create some other table for the remotes and then do the calculation. Do you think I should now even bother doing it in sql? Will there be some perf benefit at all?